# What is the legal definition of separation as it relates to ATC?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, instrument-flight-rules, visual-flight-rules, separation

ATC provides "separation" for all aircraft in class bravo airspace. What is the legal definition of separation?

Is it the same or different than the see-and-avoid rule (FAR Part 91.113(b)) where all pilots are supposed to keep their plane from hitting another plane?

If two planes in class bravo airspace were radar identified with a mode C transponder and they hit each other in VMC, who would be responsible for the collision? The pilots or ATC?

Comment: For IFR traffic, there are different kinds of separation - separation for wake turbulence, separation for parallel landings, separation from a plane that is shooting an approach, even more so for one that has lost comm's in IMC, and may be breaking of to fly to an alternate airport, etc.  For VFR, when not under ATC control, then it's see & avoid, and IFR traffic is required to see & avoid when in VMC because VFR traffic Not talking to ATC could be around.